Make primary key unique across multiple child classes with common parent
I have a django-polymorphic model like this:
from polymorphic.models import PolymorphicModel

class Item(PolymorphicModel):
    sku = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=32)

class Car(Item):
    pass

class Boat(Item):
    pass

To my horror, it's possible to create instances of the subclasses with the same primary key:
Car.objects.create(sku='123')
Boat.objects.create(sku='123') # Does NOT crash but I want it to

But of course, trying to access the created object will fail horribly:

>>> Car.objects.get(sku='123')
polymorphic.models.PolymorphicTypeInvalid: ContentType 42 for <class 'demo_application.models.Car'> #123 does not point to a subclass!

How do I ensure that all instances of Item have a unique primary key?
One option I considered is overriding the save methods of Car & Boat, or listening to pre_save signals. However, that would add a database request whenever I save them, and it feels like a hacky solution.

This is one of the reasons to use a UUIDField: to ensure uniqness, even if there are a lot of databases that generate primary keys simultenously. Using a custom field as a primary key where the person picks the value, or an autofield accross multiple databases can indeed generate such duplicates.

I would like to agree with the UUIDField suggestion. In case if you want to leave this as CharField, you should add unique=True, because just adding primary_key=True, may not guarantee uniqueness

django-polymorphic already handles PKs for polymorphic models. Your sku should not be set as PK. Instead, django-polymorphic creates internal *_ptr_id field that acts as the true PK for each child model. This field ensures uniqueness across all instances, regardless of the subclass. Just remove primary_key=True and add unique=True to ensure uniqueness within the Item model itself. By the way, I don't like Django ORM and specially django-polymorphic.You can achieve polymorphism in other ways (I like Drupal way).

I would change one line
sku = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=32)

It's not recommended to use a field as the primary key in child models within Django. Doing so can lead to unexpected behavior because Django automatically creates and uses *_ptr_id as the primary key for child models
UPDATE: I recommend using django-typed-models, this will ensure unique Primary Key for every subclass, you will not be able to set the same primary key to two objects.

But wouldn't that just move the problem? Couldn't I still create two objects with the same UUID?

@phihag see my update for the answer, I hope this will help

Consider adding sample code.
